# Double not being printed out

Tags: c++

In this code, I am making a cluster of particles and assigning them x, y and z coordinates. Then, I am evaluating the force due to this cluster at some far away point. The function `directSumUnregularized` calculates that force. 
I want to see what that force is, but for whatever reason, it is not being printed out.

This is my code:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <random>
#include "unitTestFunctions.h"
int main() {

  //set up cluster of particles
  const int numberOfParticles = 10;
  std::random_device rd{};
  std::mt19937 gen{rd()};
  std::normal_distribution<> d{0,1};

  PARTICLE *clusterOfParticles = new PARTICLE [numberOfParticles];

  double sumX{}, sumY{}, sumZ{};
  for (int ind=0; ind<numberOfParticles; ind++){
    clusterOfParticles[ind].x = d(gen);

    clusterOfParticles[ind].y = d(gen);

    clusterOfParticles[ind].z = d(gen);
  }

  //test position

  double xTest {5}, yTest{6}, zTest {7};

  double *exactForceX{nullptr}, *exactForceY{nullptr}, *exactForceZ{nullptr};
  *exactForceX = 0;
  *exactForceY = 0;
  *exactForceZ = 0;

  directSumUnregularized(numberOfParticles, exactForceX, exactForceY,
    exactForceZ, xTest, yTest, zTest,
    clusterOfParticles);

  std::cout<<"exactForce X: "<<*exactForceX<<std::endl;

delete [] clusterOfParticles;

return 0;

}
```

and my function:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <random>
#include "unitTestFunctions.h"


void directSumUnregularized(const int numberOfParticles, double *exactForceX,
  double *exactForceY, double *exactForceZ, double xTest, double yTest, double zTest,
  PARTICLE *clusterOfParticles){
    double rSq{};
    double r{};
    double dx {}, dy {}, dz{};
    const double pi = 3.1415926535897;
    double inv4pi = 1/(4*pi);
    for (int i=0; i<numberOfParticles; i++){
      dx = xTest - clusterOfParticles[i].x;
      dy = yTest - clusterOfParticles[i].y;
      dz = zTest - clusterOfParticles[i].z;
      rSq = dx*dx+dy*dy+dz*dz;
      r = sqrt(rSq);

      *exactForceX -= inv4pi*(dx/(rSq*r));
      *exactForceY -= inv4pi*(dy/(rSq*r));
      *exactForceZ -= inv4pi*(dz/(rSq*r));
    }
    return;
  }
```

how should I go about this?

Comment: I think you are not understanding how pointers work. They need to point to valid memory. In this case, the simplest way is to pass the address of a valid `double` variable.

Comment: You should go about it by using your debugger to run your code one line at a time, inspect the values of all variables, and observe your program's logical execution flow, as it happens. This is what a debugger is for. Being able able to effectively use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer. This looks like an excellent opportunity for you to learn how to use a debugger. Spending a little bit of time doing this now means you'll be able to find and fix your own bugs in the future.

Comment: When you say "it is not being printed out", do you mean "nothing is happening" or "my program crashes"? I think you probably are getting a "segmentation fault" error.

Comment: Just curious, if pi is a constant (obviously) then 1/(4pi) would be constant as well, don't you think? Or you expect different result on each function call?

Comment: If you want point to pointer use **

Comment: Things i see, can be a problem: ```double *exactForceX{nullptr}, *exactForceY{nullptr}, *exactForceZ{nullptr};
  *exactForceX = 0;
  *exactForceY = 0;
  *exactForceZ = 0; directSumUnregularized(numberOfParticles, exactForceX, exactForceY,
    exactForceZ,...``` ```void directSumUnregularized(const int numberOfParticles, double *exactForceX,
  double *exactForceY, double *exactForceZ,``` Pointing to pointers without pointing ``nullptr`` very nice trick.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding exactForceX/Y/Z, in order to work, it has to be like this:

```
//test position

double xTest = 6, yTest = 6, zTest = 7;
double exactForceX = 0, exactForceY = 0, exactForceZ = 0;

directSumUnregularized(umberOfParticles, &exactForceX, &exactForceY,
    &exactForceZ, xTest, yTest, zTest,
    clusterOfParticles);

std::cout << "exactForce X: " << exactForceX << std::endl;
```

1st, define (& initialize) the 3 variables:

```
double exactForceX = 0, exactForceY = 0, exactForceZ = 0;
```

2nd, deliver the 3 addresses to the function, to allow it to store the results.

Answer (score 0):

The problematic section is

```
  double *exactForceX{nullptr}, *exactForceY{nullptr}, *exactForceZ{nullptr};
  *exactForceX = 0;
  *exactForceY = 0;
  *exactForceZ = 0;
```

What exactly is this doing?

```
double *exactForceX{nullptr};
*exactForceX = 0;
```

You are creating a pointer with the value of `nullptr`, attempting to dereference it and assign the value 0. Dereferencing a `nullptr` is undefined behaviour.

To fix it you need the address-of operator `&`

```
double exactForceX = 0;
double exactForceY = 0;
double exactForceZ = 0;

  directSumUnregularized(numberOfParticles, &exactForceX, &exactForceY,
    &exactForceZ, xTest, yTest, zTest,
    clusterOfParticles);
```

---

It seems that there is some confusion on how pointers work. I like to use a simple example like this.

```
double value = 12345;
double *pointer_to_value = &value;
std::cout << "value " << value << std::endl;
std::cout << "&value " << &value << std::endl;
std::cout << "pointer_to_value " << pointer_to_value << std::endl;
std::cout << "*pointer_to_value " << *pointer_to_value << std::endl;
```

This will give the output that looks like: (The address may be different for you)

```
value 12345                                                                                                                                                  
&value 0x7ffc601869b0                                                                                                                                        
pointer_to_value 0x7ffc601869b0                                                                                                                              
*pointer_to_value 12345
```

The point (heh) is that *a pointer must point to a valid location*. That is, either the location of a variable, or a call to `new`. In this case, the valid location is the location of the variable `value`.

See also: [What is a segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-a-segmentation-fault)